# MongoDB how to connect Roles to Users using mongoose Schema

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql, mongoose-schema

I want to build an application where users can register as either "private" or as a "company", where if users register as a company they will have further options to choose, for example "package 1", "package 2", "package 3" etc. These additional options are the different "roles".

I'm thinking about what best practice would be here. I'm using `MongoDB`, so should I create a single "UserSchema", where I include everything or should I also create some kind of "RoleSchema" ?

So far I have something like this:

**User.js:**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  roleType: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "roles"
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

**Roles.js**

```
const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  role_name: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = Roles = mongoose.model("roles", RoleSchema);
```

Would this be a good way or are there possibly other and better ways of doing this? I'm kinda new to MongoDB

Thanks in advance